# Does FileOutputStream is persistent after upgrading my app?

Tags: android, file, save, upgrade

In my app I save some files using FileOutputStream class:

```
    FileOutputStream fos;
    fos = openFileOutput("my_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    os.writeObject(classToSave);
    os.close();
```

If I upgrade my app anche the I execute:

```
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    fis = openFileInput("my_file");
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    myData = (MyClass) is.readObject();
    is.close();
```

does *fis* is null or it contains the class that I saved before upgrade?

Comment: you are reading of object of class MyClass, not a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file itself will be still there after the upgrade. If you can retrieve the serialised object depends on which changes you made to `MyClass` in the source code.

Comment: Then there are no problems.